VMWARE - Ubuntu 2022.04 - screen resize
Using REDHAT - and CENTOS under VMWARE - the screen autoresizes when I adjust the vmware console. ie: It starts out as an 800x600 screen - I maximize the vmware window and the Linux GUI auto-resizes. I shrink it and it auto-resizes.
How do I enable this in VMWARE using UBUNTU-2022.4
I find this for VIRTUAL BOX - not VMWARE
How do you resize the standard Ubuntu Desktop inside of Virtualbox?
Is there a VMWARE version of this tool kit?  I thought this would have been installed auto-magically...

NOTE: If I go into the screen resolution tool in ubuntu I can change the size, but that is a manual process - I specifically want the autmoatic process.

To answer, guiverc - I am using the DESKTOP install

Installed XRDP it does the same thing.
